# AJAX get then redirect after success

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, get

I am trying to use ajax to GET form data to send to api url then redirect the user who filled out form to a thankyou page.

```
<form id="valform">
<!-- form elements -->
</form>
<div id="status_message"></div>
```

Simple form code is above and the ajax code is under

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var API_URL = 'http://www.some-api-provider.com/api.php';    
$('#valform').on('submit', function (e){
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: API_URL,
  data: $('#valform').serialize(),
  success: function () {
    window.location.href = "thankyou.html";

  },
  error: function () {
    alert('There was a problem!'); // do something better than this!
  }
});
return false;
});
```

Is there problems with this code?  I keep getting the alert message in the GET section so i'm assuming something is wrong in there.

Comment: Cross-domain AJAX is a problem in itself.

Comment: is there any authentication parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your file is hosted on the same domain as the `API_URL`, AJAX will stop your request, That is why you are seeing the error message. This is to stop [XSS (Cross Site Scripting)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), a hacking technique. This is called the [same-domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) policy.

Comment: Host the file on the same server?

Comment: Or use the server to gather the API data, via a proxy hosted on the same domain.

Comment: I can't host the file on the same server, the API url is to an affiliate

Comment: @user1532944 try `crossDomain : true,`